# google/apiclient is not getting installed

Tags: laravel, google-api-client

I am trying to install google/apiclient:^2.0 in my project and it gives me errors as below,

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.8.*, found laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v7.30.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires google/apiclient 2.0 -> satisfiable by google/apiclient[v2.0.0].
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0 requires monolog/monolog ^1.17 -> found monolog/monolog[1.17.0, ..., 1.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

[image]

Please help me out with the same.
Thanks & Regards

Comment: first thing first, the error message says, `google/apiclient` **require** monolog version 1.17 (you have 2.2.0). try using the `google/apiclient` version 2.3 (e.g. `composer require google/apiclient:^2.3.0`). hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just turn off windows real time security and it works

Comment: The comment by @Bagus Tesa helped me with my issue